# mergExt - Avoiding that play an audio stops mergAVCamSet

Tags: audio, livecode

I'm using mergAV to record video on a LiveCode project for iOS. All works fine but when I play an audio mergAVCamSet stops to work and seems it freezes. Is there a way to play audio and have mergAVCamSet continue to work or the two operations collide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the audio category to play and record try:

```
mergAVAudioSessionSetCategory "play and record",false,false,false,true
```

Note the true at the end there toggles whether the audio will come out of the speaker instead of the receiver.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.For my particular case, I found that the right code should be: `mergAVAudioSessionSetCategory "ambient","true"`